# Xcode custom font won't load numbers

Tags: iphone, xcode, uifont

I'm making an app which uses a custom font (Rockwell.ttf). I have done everything correctly and it works when I am using for `UILabels` (text only), however, when I try to use it with a `UILabel` that contains numbers, the font does not work with the numbers.

In finder when I open up the .ttf it shows the text as well as the numbers but as soon as I import it into Xcode, the numbers dissapear and I'm left only with the text! Please help.

Answer (score 0):

try with some other .ttf fonts and check if they show the numbers. This way you can will be able to identify if the problem is with the .ttf font or with the iOS :)

Comment: I have done so already and as soon as I import the .ttf from finder into Xcode, the numbers at the base of the preview dissapear.